# reducing nested object key value inside an an array

Tags: javascript, object, nested, duplicates, reduce

i have the following arrays

```
array1 = [
    {a:{key:1 , value: 10} , b:{key:1 , value:12} , c:{key:1 , value: 5} , d:{key:1 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:2 , value: 10} , b:{key:2 , value:12} , c:{key:2 , value: 5} , d:{key:2 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:3 , value: 10} , b:{key:3 , value:12} , c:{key:3 , value: 5} , d:{key:3 , value:2}},
]
```

```
array2 = [
    {a:{key:1 , value: 10} , b:{key:1 , value:12} , c:{key:1 , value: 5} , d:{key:1 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:2 , value: 10} , b:{key:2 , value:12} , c:{key:2 , value: 5} , d:{key:2 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:4 , value: 10} , b:{key:4 , value:12} , c:{key:4 , value: 5} , d:{key:4 , value:2}},
]
```

reduced array based on `key` should look like this:

```
combinedArray= [
    {a:{key:1 , value: 20} , b:{key:1 , value:24} , c:{key:1 , value: 10} , d:{key:1 , value:4}},
    {a:{key:2 , value: 20} , b:{key:2 , value:24} , c:{key:2 , value: 10} , d:{key:2 , value:4}},
    {a:{key:3 , value: 10} , b:{key:3 , value:12} , c:{key:3 , value: 5} , d:{key:3 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:4 , value: 10} , b:{key:4 , value:12} , c:{key:4 , value: 5} , d:{key:4 , value:2}},
]
```

first i tried to merge the two arrays using `const mergedArray = [...array1, ...array2]`

now i want to check for key duplicates. for example, if there is key1 in both array1 and array2, remove the duplicates then combine the values of that key.

this is what i have tried but it is only iterating through `a.key` only:

```
function kdeAdder(param) {
    const array = [param.a]
    let tempHistory = [];
    for(let x=0;x<array.length;x++){
        array[x].forEach((item)=>{
            let noMatch = true; 
            if(tempHistory.length > 0) {
                tempHistory.forEach((tempItem, i)=>{
                    if(item.key === tempItem.key) {
                        tempHistory[i].value += item.value;
                        noMatch = !noMatch; 
                    }
                });
            }
            return (noMatch) ? tempHistory.push(item) : null;
        });

    }
    return tempHistory;
}
kdeAdder(mergedArray);
```

Comment: Interesting use-case. Two notes:
You want to combine arrays of objects to a single array but your initial value is an object instead of an array.
Also it is unclear what mergedArray contains and how you got to that value.

Comment: I can also just assume that the value of a.key is considered a unique identifier for each entry. Is that correct?

Comment: my initials are Two arrays no? array1 and array2

Comment: yes `a.key` is a unique identifier. `a.key`, `b.key`, `c.key` etc all belong to the same set. they will have the same key number as the array position +1

Comment: Please edit your question and explain how exactly the merged array is accomplished. It looks like values are added, but nothing in your post explains this.

Comment: This is the question: how to sum values when the unique identifier is equal.

Comment: does this make more sense? did it clarify?

Comment: In your example the outer objects always have the properties `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Is this always the case? These four properties always share the same value for their inner `key` value. Is this always the case? The inner objects always have `key` and `value` properties. Is this always the case? If not, can you give an example that shows more variation?

Comment: yes. it is always the case for all three scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed the `key` inner property is commonly shared by the four "a", "b", "c", "d" objects in an outer object, the `a.key` value  can be used to identify which outer objects should merge.

You could group all objects (irrespective of whether they occur in `array1` or `array2`) by that `a.key`, and then aggregate objects that occur in the same group. Both of these actions can be accomplished with a `reduce` call:

```js
const aggregate = (objects) =>
    objects.reduce((x, y) => ({
        a: { key: x.a.key, value: x.a.value + y.a.value },
        b: { key: x.b.key, value: x.b.value + y.b.value },
        c: { key: x.c.key, value: x.c.value + y.c.value },
        d: { key: x.d.key, value: x.d.value + y.d.value },
    }));
                                
const merge = (array1, array2) =>
    Object.values(array1.concat(array2).reduce((acc, obj) => {
        (acc[obj.a.key] ??= []).push(obj);
        return acc;
    }, {})).map(aggregate);
    
const array1 = [
    {a:{key:1 , value: 10} , b:{key:1 , value:12} , c:{key:1 , value: 5} , d:{key:1 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:2 , value: 10} , b:{key:2 , value:12} , c:{key:2 , value: 5} , d:{key:2 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:3 , value: 10} , b:{key:3 , value:12} , c:{key:3 , value: 5} , d:{key:3 , value:2}},
];

const array2 = [
    {a:{key:1 , value: 10} , b:{key:1 , value:12} , c:{key:1 , value: 5} , d:{key:1 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:2 , value: 10} , b:{key:2 , value:12} , c:{key:2 , value: 5} , d:{key:2 , value:2}},
    {a:{key:4 , value: 10} , b:{key:4 , value:12} , c:{key:4 , value: 5} , d:{key:4 , value:2}},
]

console.log(merge(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first reduce the output to a single object since its a sort of accumulation of numbers, and then get the format you want as the second step.

```js
const array1 = [ { a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 }, }, { a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 }, }, { a: { key: 3, value: 10 }, b: { key: 3, value: 12 }, c: { key: 3, value: 5 }, d: { key: 3, value: 2 }, }, ]; const array2 = [ { a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 }, }, { a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 }, }, { a: { key: 4, value: 10 }, b: { key: 4, value: 12 }, c: { key: 4, value: 5 }, d: { key: 4, value: 2 }, }, ];

const mergedArray = [...array1, ...array2];
const keys = []

const reducedOutput = mergedArray.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([mainKey, { key, value }]) => {
    // mainKey is a, b, c, d in your case
    if (!prev[mainKey]) {
      prev[mainKey] = {};
    }
    // key is 1, 2, 3, 4 in your case
    if (!keys.includes(key)) {
      keys.push(key)
    }
    prev[mainKey][key] = prev[mainKey][key]
      ? prev[mainKey][key] + value
      : value;
  });
  return prev;
}, {});

const output = keys.map(key => {
  const obj = {}
  Object.entries(reducedOutput).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    obj[k] = {key, value: v[key]}
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(output)
```

This will work with any other keys for a, b, c, d keys and 1, 2, 3, 4 keys you have used in two levels.

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @xtyy, check this out and let me know if you need any clarifications !

Comment: I find it hard to follow. And what does keys.map accomplish when keys is an empty array?

Comment: can you explain how this line works? `? prev[mainKey][key] + value: value;`

Comment: @xtyy, it checks whether the key exists if yes then add value to the existing value or else assign the value for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could group with the `key` property and the outer property.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 } }, { a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 } }, { a: { key: 3, value: 10 }, b: { key: 3, value: 12 }, c: { key: 3, value: 5 }, d: { key: 3, value: 2 } }],
    array2 = [{ a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 } }, { a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 } }, { a: { key: 4, value: 10 }, b: { key: 4, value: 12 }, c: { key: 4, value: 5 }, d: { key: 4, value: 2 } }],
    result = Object.values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, { key, value }]) => {
            r[key] ??= {};
            r[key][k] ??= { key, value: 0 };
            r[key][k].value += value;
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following provided code implements an approach which tries to find a balance in between **1st** being agnostic to any array item's current and future structure except for both property names, `key` and `value`, of any array item's second level structure and **2nd** how to handle the merger of other unknown second level data.

Therefore the general approach creates an object based lookup from the shorter `sourceList` where each item gets referred to via the value of its second level `key` property, whereas the longer `targetList` will be [`reduced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to create the final result of merged items from both arrays.

Since approach and implementation are unaware of an items first level structure, one has to `reduce` again all of a currently processed item's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). For each of a target item's unknown entry one can rely on such an entry's 2nd level properties, `key` and `value`. From all the available data, either known or unknown, one can aggregate the common merger of both the source- and the target-item; their `value`s will be totaled and both of their unknown rest data will be merged by spread syntax, where the latter is the approach's trade off/compromise.

```js
function aggregateFirstValueKeyBasedLookup(lookup, item) {
  lookup[Object.values(item)[0]?.key ?? ''] = item;
  return lookup;  
}
function createKeyBasedValueMergerFromSourceLookup(
  { lookup = {}, result = [] }, targetItem, idx, arr,
) {
  let currentLookupKey;

  result.push(Object
    .entries(targetItem)
    .reduce((merger, [
      targetEntryKey, {
        key, value: targetEntryValue = 0, ...targetEntryRest
      }
    ]) => {
      currentLookupKey = key;

      const sourceItem = lookup[key] ?? {};
      const {
        value: sourceEntryValue = 0, ...sourceEntryRest
      } = sourceItem[targetEntryKey] ?? {};

      return Object.assign(merger, {
        [ targetEntryKey ]: {
          key,
          value: (targetEntryValue + sourceEntryValue),
          ...targetEntryRest,
          ...sourceEntryRest,
        },            
      });

    }, {})
  );
  // delete already processed source-items from lookup.
  Reflect.deleteProperty(lookup, currentLookupKey);

  if (idx >= arr.length - 1) {
    // finalize the result by ...
    result.push(
      // ...pushing all of the lookup's
      //    unprocessed source-items.
      ...[...Object.values(lookup)]
    );
  }  
  return { lookup, result };
}


const array1 = [{
  a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 }
}, {
  a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 }
}, {
  a: { key: 3, value: 10 }, b: { key: 3, value: 12 }, c: { key: 3, value: 5 }, d: { key: 3, value: 2 }
}];
const array2 = [{
  a: { key: 1, value: 10 }, b: { key: 1, value: 12 }, c: { key: 1, value: 5 }, d: { key: 1, value: 2 }
}, {
  a: { key: 2, value: 10 }, b: { key: 2, value: 12 }, c: { key: 2, value: 5 }, d: { key: 2, value: 2 }
}, {
  a: { key: 4, value: 10 }, b: { key: 4, value: 12 }, c: { key: 4, value: 5 }, d: { key: 4, value: 2 }
}];

const [ targetList, sourceList ]
  = [array1, array2].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

const sourceLookup = sourceList
  .reduce(aggregateFirstValueKeyBasedLookup, Object.create(null));

console.log({ sourceLookup });

const { result: mergedItemList } = targetList
  .reduce(createKeyBasedValueMergerFromSourceLookup, {
    lookup: sourceLookup, result: [],
  });

console.log({ mergedItemList });


// - changed item structure which keeps
//   just the most necessary pattern.

const newItemStructureList1 = [{
  quick: { key: 'foo', value: 33, biz: 'biz' },
  brown: { key: 'foo', value: 22, baz: 'baz' },
  fox: { key: 'foo', value: 11, buzz: 'buzz' },
}, {
  quick: { key: 'bar', value: 11, baz: 'baz' },
  brown: { key: 'bar', value: 33, biz: 'biz' },
  fox: { key: 'bar', value: 22, booz: 'booz' },
}, {
  quick: { key: 'baz', value: 22, baz: 'baz' },
  brown: { key: 'baz', value: 11, biz: 'biz' },
  fox: { key: 'baz', value: 33, booz: 'booz' },
}];
const newItemStructureList2 = [{
  brown: { key: 'foo', value: 11, baz: 'baz' },
  fox: { key: 'foo', value: 33, booz: 'booz' },
  quick: { key: 'foo', value: 22, baz: 'baz' },
}, {
  fox: { key: 'baz', value: 33, buzz: 'buzz' },
  quick: { key: 'baz', value: 11, biz: 'biz' },
  brown: { key: 'baz', value: 33, baz: 'baz' },
}];

const [ target, source ]
  = [newItemStructureList1, newItemStructureList2].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

const lookup = source
  .reduce(aggregateFirstValueKeyBasedLookup, Object.create(null));

console.log({ lookup });

const { result: mergedItems } = target
  .reduce(createKeyBasedValueMergerFromSourceLookup, { lookup, result: [] });

console.log({ mergedItems });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```